# Check if there are two (or more) custom object with the same attribute value in a python list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have this "problem":

I have a *Python List* containing custom object like this `list = [Object1, Object2, Object3, ..., ObjectN]`and i want to check if exist some elements with the same attribute value.

So the function `checkDuplicateAttr(list)` should return None if all objects have different attribute value, while return the list of duplicate attribute objects if not.

Example:

```
Foo = newObject(value=1, name="foo")
Bar = newObject(value=4, name="bar")
Car = newObject(value=1, name="car")
list = [Foo, Bar, Car]

if x = checkDuplicateAttr(list) is None:
    print("There are no duplicate attribute values")
else:
    print("There are duplicate value elements", x)
```

And for my example the output should be:

```
OUTPUT:
There are duplicate Value elements: [Foo, Car]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this below code help you:

```
from typing import List
from itertools import groupby


class MyCustomObj:
    def __init__(self, value, name):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


def checkDuplicateAttr(objects: List[MyCustomObj]):
    obj_group_by_value = [
        list(g[1])
        for g in groupby(
            sorted(objects, key=lambda obj: obj.value), lambda obj: obj.value
        )
    ]
    return list(filter(lambda objs: len(objs) > 1, obj_group_by_value)) or None


Foo = MyCustomObj(value=1, name="foo")
Bar = MyCustomObj(value=4, name="bar")
Car = MyCustomObj(value=1, name="car")

x = checkDuplicateAttr([Foo, Bar, Car])
if x is None:
    print("There are no duplicate attribute values")
else:
    print(
        "There are duplicate value elements {}".format(
            x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x
        )
    )
```